# Are there any books solely about the Umayyad Invasion of Gaul?

Tags: book, umayyad-caliphate

I am very fascinated by the [Umayyad Invasion of Gaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umayyad_invasion_of_Gaul) (the Arabic wiki-page on this subject is very interesting, though it starts with a lengthy description of the condition of Franks) and I am looking for a book SOLELY from start to end dedicated to this subject. I tried to find it on the Internet but to no avail, maybe there is not a single book on the Umayyad Invasion of Gaul due to the ephemerality of the invasion: I don't know for sure; but if indeed there is, please give reference/URL address.

EDIT: The book is preferable, but any research paper on the subject will do also!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why it was down-voted? Any reason?

Comment: I believe it is because they dont really like questions looking for a source.  See https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3866/what-should-be-our-policy-on-requests-for-sources-or-references?cb=1 .  I upvoted you so you are back to zero at least.

Comment: Modern historians  do not typically use the name "[Gaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaul)" to refer to this area at this time -- After the Merovingian victory at [Soissons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Soissons_(486)) in 486, it's the "Frankish kingdom" or just "France". [There are many results if you do a Google Books search for the Battle of Tours](https://www.google.com/search?q=battle+of+tours&source=lnms&tbm=bks&bih=964).

Comment: @Spencer Thank you for providing me with reference books! But I think that those books only speak about Charles Martel's role in the battle not on the Umayyad Invasion of Francia on the whole, 'from start to end', as I have said.

Comment: Yes, generally for users, I'd suggest asking questions about the thing they want to read up on. (EG: "How much do we really know about the Umayyad invasion of Gaul?") and then hope answers reference good reading material on the subject. That's probably an unreasonable thing to expect out of new users such as yourself though, and it might not even pay off.

Comment: @Spencer The 1st book on the row is very discriminative btw, absolutely unworthy of reading, it says "Mohammed, the PROPHET for PROFIT" and other filthy statements, it promotes hatred.

Comment: @Tug'Tegin - I don't get that when I click that llink, but it appears to be a google search link, so it may be "localized" to give you a different result than me (but I agree that's gross, and should not be read by anyone).

Comment: @T.E.D. The title of the book is just "Battle of Tours" with a grey-ish picture of a mounted warrior on the background, It says "A NEW LOOK AT AN OLD ENEMY" labelling Muslims as enemies, you can look at the contents of it.

Comment: @Tug'Tegin Agreed. It's unfortunate the way Google search results are ordered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider this doctoral dissertation: *The hammer and the crescent: Contacts between Andalusi Muslims, Franks, and their successors in three waves of Muslim expansion into Francia*, available at https://repository.upenn.edu/dissertations/AAI9112639/

It is based on an analysis of the original source material.  You can preview the introductory chapter for free.

Comment: Despite my ticking the above answer as accepted, any further answers will be appreciated!!!

Comment: What would you suggest to get the entire dissertation? Should I write to the author like asking "for a favor" of sending me the entire text via e-mail?

Comment: Contact the author is always a good method; it is also may be available via inter-library loan from these libraries: https://www.worldcat.org/title/hammer-and-the-crescent-contacts-bewtween-andalusi-muslims-franks-and-their-successors-in-three-waves-of-muslim-expansion-into-francia/oclc/1025680426

Comment: You can also order it from ProQuest, for $38.  You can find the option on the original link, if you follow the directions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_E._Watson has info about the author & his other books.